# Is there any way to assign default values globally for a localization extension?

Tags: c#, wpf

The problem statement is, I end up copy and pasting following block of xaml lines in all my views.

```
lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="WPF.Common"
lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="global"
xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com">
```

Is there some mechanism to put this assignment in some file and derive in all views?

Comment: Attached behavior which sets other attached properties.

Comment: Thanks @Sinatr for the answer. But sorry I don't get you, I am new in WPF. Can you please give an example or better explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a default style for type UserControl in your application resources.

XAML :

```
 <Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:lex="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
   <Application.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="UserControl">
           <Setter Property="lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture" Value="en" />
           <Setter Property="lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly" Value="WPF.Common" />
           <Setter Property="lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary" Value="global" />
       </Style>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Comment: Implicit styles does not work with inherited classes. For example, this style won't be applied to any view that inherit from UserControl

Answer (score 1):

You can use attached behavior, here is very simplistic (dumb) version:

```
public class MyBevavior
{
    public static bool GetProperty(DependencyObject obj) => (bool)obj.GetValue(PropertyProperty);
    public static void SetProperty(DependencyObject obj, bool value) => obj.SetValue(PropertyProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Property", typeof(bool), typeof(Class), new PropertyMetadata(false, (d, e) =>
        {
            LocalizeDictionary.SetDesignCulture(d, "en");
            ResxLocalizationProvider.SetDefaultAssembly(d, "WPF.Common");
            ResxLocalizationProvider.SetDefaultDictionary(d, "global")
        }));
}
```

Then xaml become *shorter*:

```
<Window local:MyBehavior.Property="true" ...>
...
```

Note, you can make it configurable with some meaningful parameter. In its current form it is `bool`, which is stupid, perhaps it make sense to pass `en` as `string`.

Or you can make base type for all your views, e.g. `MyWindow`, where you set those in constructor.

Or you can move that into a `OnLoad` event of every window.

Answer (score 1):

why dont just use style defined in resource dictionary?

```
<Style x:Key="ViewStyle">
   <Setter Property="lex:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture" Value="en" />
   <Setter Property="lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly" Value="WPF.Common" />
   <Setter Property="lex:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary" Value="global" />
</Style>
```

and then use the style in your views:

```
<UserControl Style="{StaticResource ViewStyle}">
<Page Style="{StaticResource ViewStyle}">
<Window Style="{StaticResource ViewStyle}">
```

BTW, Visual studio provides couple of nice features to simplify this kind of routines.

For example, you can create [custom Item Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tsyyf0yh.aspx) that will generate the view with all the stuff you need. The template can contain also ViewModel for the view if you wish. It really easy to create Custom Item Template.

Similarly you can create [custom code snippet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx), which is even simpler. When you write `lex' and then press tab, it will generate the stuff for you.